# Read Thousandths Digit and Inrement Hundredths Digit if Nonzero (C++)

Tags: c++, rounding

I have a list of doubles, and I need to analyze each number and do the following:

1) Check thousandths digit.
2) If ^ nonzero, round the hundredths digit and maintain the rest of the number.

So going by this:

10.111567 would become 10.121567

Alternatively:

10.110567 would remain 10.110567 because the thousandths digit is zero.

Comment: Surely `10.111567` rounded is `10.11` unless you are rounding up, and then surely it should be `10.12` not `10.121567`. If you were to round it again, should it become `10.131567`?

Comment: @Dariusz It's for a specific application. Rather than down-voting, could you please just help me?

Comment: a) I didnt downvote, b) I wanted to make sure you really meant what you wrote, c) your problem seemed trivial and I couldn't believe you were actually asking that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do exactly what you wrote in question's topic: **Read Thousandths Digit and Increment Hundredths Digit if Nonzero**

```
double val = 13.412412;
int thousandsDigit = (val*1000)%10;
if (thousandsDigit != 0) {
  val+= 0.01;
}
```